# When do I need to subclass UIViewController and when can I just instantiate it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am learning iOS programming through the Big Nerd Ranch guide by Hillegass and Conway. I’m writing an app of my own as I go through the book, and one of the questions that has been bugging me is exactly when I need to subclass UIViewController (and its ilk) and when I can just instantiate it.

For example, my app consists of generic building blocks: the interface is tabbed, and the tabs lead to a UITableView, a UINavigationController that creates UITableViews, and so on. Following the book’s instructions, I have subclassed UITableViewController to create the table views. However, in creating the UITabBarController that contains all of my app’s content, it seems sufficient to instantiate a UITabBarController and then add a bunch of views to it. (All of this is done in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of my app delegate. Since most of my app consists of simple combinations of basic UI parts, I’m trying to do build the UI programmatically whenever possible.)

I get the impression that what I should be doing is creating a subclass of UIViewController (or UITableViewController or whatever) for *every* interface in my project. This seems weird to me, since most of these classes would only ever be instantiated once. Am I just misunderstanding how OO should be used in this case? (I have a good amount of programming experience but relatively little has been with OOP.) Should I be creating a subclass for each and every screen that the user will see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have two types of UIViewControllers in iOS. "Container" viewControllers and "Content" viewcontrollers. Both are subclasses of UIViewController but have very different purposes.

The Container type is what the UINavigationController and UITabController are. They are rarely subclassed and typically used as is (in fact, I believe Apple doesn't allow the subclassing of UINavigationController at all). These "Containers" take care of moving "Content" view controller around for you. They do not have much content of their own, beyond adding things like a tab bar or a navigation bar.

The "Content" view controller are the ones you create most of the time. You will rarely be able to use a UIViewController as is, because it will not have any functionality. That is why you subclass them. These are meant to represent a single "screenful" of content. So in effect, every "screen" the user sees should be controlled by a UIViewController subclass.

The UITableViewController is simply a specialized sublass of UIViewController that already contains some methods for managing tables.

The way the UIKit framework was designed was for you to use subclasses of UIViewController to display content and to use out-of-the-box "Container" controllers to facilitate the management of your UIViewController subclasses.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I be creating a subclass for each and every screen that the user will see?

If each view requires different logic, yes.

Don't shy away from creating new classes for conceptually separate things. Programmers coming from non-OOP to OOP might feel that a file with only a small amount of code is a waste. Suppress this feeling. Classes are cheap, and help enormously to organise your thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You need a subclass of UIViewController if you want to do any of the following (not an exhaustive list, but some examples)

- customize the view hierarchy when the view hierarchy is loaded (in
  `viewDidLoad`)
- provide some behaviour as the view controller's views become visible
  (or not) (in `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear:`,
  etc.)
- clean up after yourself as needed in `viewDidUnload`
- create outlets to views in the hierarchy so you can adjust them as
  needed in the above lifecycle methods

Answer (score 2):

My reasoning behind subclassing `UIViewController`, and other classes is that:

1. Almost always you must initialize variables and assign values to the instances of classes. You add subviews and set their frames, define actions for the `UIViewController` instance, etc. If this `UIViewController` instance is directly from the base class, its initialization should be done outside of it. If this initialization is required at different places for multiple times, you may have to deal with repeated initialization process.
2. So, you've compiled these processes into a method, making it reusable from wherever this `UIViewController` instance is used. But where do you want to put it? Don't you think it's much better to put it inside the subclass of UIViewController? Also, you don't even have to come up with specific name for this initialization method. Just override the default `-(id)init` from the super class.
3. Though you may think it's suffice to use `UIViewController` without subclassing it for now, as your project grows, it will be challenged to deal with reusability issues. Take some time to look at your codes. Check if there is too much repetition for such as initializing an object, or assigning values to it. If you are doing same things with an instance of a class in multiple places, compile them into a method to be reused. And as number of such methods grow, you will find the need to use subclass which will contain these relevant methods for the instance.
4. No matter the size of your project, using classes to distinguish different objects is important. Almost always, the basic essential classification is done by the framework, making it unnecessary to introduce new concept for a class. However, this doesn't mean the framework also knows how your project and its objects can be classified into. By using subclass, you can utilize every benefit the development framework can provide and still keeping the objects in your project to be as unique as possible, based on the purpose you've designed for them.

Answer (score 1):

Well about the UITabBarController you are right. There is no reason for you to subclass anything if the default behavior is sufficient. However once you need to do some custom things you will need to subclass it..

Also, why are you trying to build the GUI programmatically? For the learning curve? There is no real reason not to use InterfaceBuilder, it saves you a lot of time.

You should subclass the UITableViewController in order to get your data in the view, that is how the MVC model works. The default implementation does not offer anything in order to get your data in the view, I don't think they will ever do that in order to make sure that nothing is wasted, their 'connection' to the model object might be different from the one you want and you would end up writing an adapter if your model object is not compatible.

I hope this will help you out a bit.

And merry x-mas.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but personally I used IB in the beginning of my iOS career, but I find now that it's just a pain. It's a lot of wasted time spent making outlets and connecting them, and makes the code (IMHO) harder to understand since its spread out over more files. When you start making a lot of custom drawing, I find it more of a nuisance. Anyway, that's my two cents.